# Python - inverting a bitmap image without using ImgOps 'invert' or other built-in functions

Tags: python

I'd like to know how to invert an image in Python using PIL except that i can't use 'invert' or 'convert' or any other 'easy' ways of doing it.

any help would be appreciated. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [`im.load()`](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm)

```
pix = im.load()
print pix[x, y]
pix[x, y] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

Invert an RGB tuple like this:

```
red, green, blue = pixel
red = 256 - red
green = 256 - green
blue = 256 - blue
pixel = red, green, blue
```